# How to fix a computer that won't restart?

Tags: boot, grub2, restart

I can't restart my laptop under Ubuntu 12.04 and the screen turns black with no response after clicking the Restart button.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the terminal and edit this `/etc/default/grub` file under Ubuntu 12.04

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find now this line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

[image]

Replace it with this one:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=efi"

[image]

Save your file and close, then update Grub with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system, then try to restart your system to see if it works or not. If this is not working for you, repeat the same steps and try one of these lines instead:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=bios"

or

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=acpi"

or

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=pci"

Comment: pci worked for a L502X Dell 15 XPS. Finally!