# Power off / reboot fail - Lenovo IdeaPad 100

Tags: reboot

All i've followed is the following tutorial.:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Fixing reboot/shutdown freezes

If your machine freezes upon attempts to shutdown or reboot, try modifying /etc/default/grub. Open the file with gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub (graphical interface) or sudo nano /etc/default/grub (command-line). Any other plaintext editor (Vim, Emacs, Kate, Leafpad) is fine too. Find the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add reboot=bios to the end.

If done properly it should result in something like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"

Then save the file, run sudo update-grub and reboot in any way that's possible for you. After that, reboots and shutdowns should start working properly.

With certain hardware (notably DELL) the kernel parameter that you add needs to be **reboot=pci** (instead of reboot=bios), the procedure remains the same.
**Note:
reboot=bios did not work, but reboot=pci worked only for the 1st time. Then it freezes just like before.**

Have you got any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: Have you tried this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/193948/476968?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with Ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit

```
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=efi"
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=bios"
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=acpi"
-) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=pci"
```

nothing worked so i restored the default doc.

In the BIOS I changed at the Table "EXIT" "OS Optimized Defaults" to "Win8 64bit" and klicked "Load Default Settings". Saved and it works now with Kernel 3.19.0-51-generic

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problems with ideapad 100 follow these steps:
Type in terminal:
1) sudo pluma /etc/default/grub
2) modify the following line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
3) save the document
4) sudo update-grub
5) restart your laptop

Since it's done my laptop can reboot/power off smoothly under Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
Note: I tried to do the same under Lubuntu 15.10 64bit. However mdifications above did not work.